# How to set X-XSS-Protection in Apache to prevent rendering when an attack is detected?

Tags: wordpress

I am confused about placing X-XSS-Protection in Apache. I use sitecheck.sucuri.net and I recommend adding X-XSS-Protection. How to do it?

I try setup in `.htaccess` like this=

````
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
...```

Is that true, but it doesn't work. How to do it?
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
Header unset Pragma
Header append Cache-Control "public"
</IfModule>
...
```

`Header set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"`: Enable XSS filtering. Instead of sanitizing the page, the browser will prevent page rendering if an attack is detected.

Please read this:
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-XSS-Protection